# Firebase CLI not deploying

Tags: firebase, deployment, command-line-interface

I've just installed firebase CLI on to my computer  - windows 10..

However, when run `npm install` in the functions fold I get this warning..

```
npm WARN dialogflow-fulfillment@0.4.1 requires a peer of actions-on-google@^2.1.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.


audited 975 packages in 6.407s

30 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Which I do... But then I get this error when I try to deploy the project..

```
=== Deploying to 'udemy-demo-assistant-59b6a'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'actions-on-google'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Udemy\firebase\functions\node_modules\dialogflow-fulfillment\src\dialogflow-fulfillment.js
- \firebase\functions\index.js
- \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

and we are back to square one..

How do I resolve this issue

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

The package.json

{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}